# GridView inside Expandable list in android

Tags: android, gridview, view, adapter, expandablelistview

I want to put an gridview with images inside an expandable list...I've already make that, but the gridview don't show all item...

How can i make my expandable list child adapt to the gridview size?

**LIST ADAPTER**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
    String[]            catg    = { "Administração, Escritorio e Industria", "Cultura e Entretenimento", "Educação e Crianças", "Eventos e Estado do tempo", "Amigos, Familia e Habitações", "Multimédia", "Diversos", "Números e Letras", "Restaurantes e Hoteis", "Desporto, Saude e Beleza", "Lojas", "Turismo e Natureza", "Transportes" };

    Context             myctx;


    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewGroup item = getViewGroupChild(convertView, parent);
        GridView label = (GridView) item.findViewById(ipvc.estg.placebook.R.id.gridview);
        label.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(parent.getContext(), groupPosition+1));
        return item;
    }

    private ViewGroup getViewGroupChild(View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // The parent will be our ListView from the ListActivity
        if (convertView instanceof ViewGroup)
        {
            return (ViewGroup) convertView;
        }
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        ViewGroup item = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(ipvc.estg.placebook.R.layout.expandable_list_row, null);
        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
    {
        return catg[groupPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount()
    {
        return catg.length;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }



    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View item = getViewGroupGroup(convertView, parent);

        TextView text = (TextView) item.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        text.setText(catg[groupPosition]);
        return item;
    }

    private View getViewGroupGroup(View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // The parent will be our ListView from the ListActivity
        if (convertView instanceof View)
        {
            return (View) convertView;
        }
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View item1 = (View) inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, null);

        return item1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

**LIST ROW LAYOUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <GridView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="50dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you show the GridAdapter? because i already implement expandable listview inside navigation drawer, and i want to add gridview contain images inside expandable listview child.

Comment: Hey can you please share the full coding?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I've done tons of searches my own for solving this situation, but didn't find anything so far, so i've made a workaround.

This workaround assumes that you know / can retrieve the width of your columns, and the height of your grid cell renderers (the dp size set in your layout xmls).

You should insert a few more lines inside your `ExpandableListAdapter`'s `getChildView` method:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewGroup item = getViewGroupChild(convertView, parent);
    GridView label = (GridView) item.findViewById(ipvc.estg.placebook.R.id.gridview);
    label.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(parent.getContext(), groupPosition+1));

    // initialize the following variables (i've done it based on your layout
    // note: rowHeightDp is based on my grid_cell.xml, that is the height i've
    //    assigned to the items in the grid.
    final int spacingDp = 10;
    final int colWidthDp = 50;
    final int rowHeightDp = 20;

    // convert the dp values to pixels
    final float COL_WIDTH = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * colWidthDp;
    final float ROW_HEIGHT = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * rowHeightDp;
    final float SPACING = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * spacingDp;

    // calculate the column and row counts based on your display
    final int colCount = (int)Math.floor((parentView.getWidth() - (2 * SPACING)) / (COL_WIDTH + SPACING));
    final int rowCount = (int)Math.ceil((intValues.size() + 0d) / colCount);

    // calculate the height for the current grid
    final int GRID_HEIGHT = Math.round(rowCount * (ROW_HEIGHT + SPACING));

    // set the height of the current grid
    label.getLayoutParams().height = GRID_HEIGHT;

    return item;
}
```

With the addition above i was able to produce the following displayed layouts:

[image: expandable list with grid - portrait]

and

[image: expandable list with grid - landscape]

I hope it can help you as well.

Comment: You're welcome, happy coding further! ;) also +1 for the orig. question, let's hope others will find it useful as well

Comment: @rekaszeru can you please tell me what the `parentView` and `intValues` stands for ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Anuja Piyadigama: `parentView` is a view (optionally containing the grid), who's width can be determined, and matches the width of the grid. If you have fixed grid width, you can use it there. The `intValues` is a list of integers that are fed into the grid. Based on the number of these integers, and knowing the column count you are able to calculate how many rows are necessary. Hope this clears up things a bit.

Comment: @rekaszeru thanks for the reply. I am having the `ExpandableListView` in `LinearLayout` in one XML file and the `GridView` is inside another `LinearLayout` in another XML file. So do I need to get the `LinearLayout` as my **parentView** or is that a single Grid are you talking about? I'm feeding the Grid content from a seperate JSON where it can be increase. So how can I count the **intValues** Thank you

Comment: @Anuja Piyadigama, you see if the `parent` parameter does work for you or not (as I understand, it refers to the `LinearLayout` you are looking for, so instead of using `parentView` you could use the `parent` parameter's width); as of the `intValues`, it does not matter that the length of this list changes, with a proper `BaseAdapter` extension for the `ExpandableListView` you can call on it `notifyDatasetChanged()` whenever it is necessary, so you just feel free to count the items in the JSON list, and calculate with it.

Comment: Hey can you please add code for new GridAdapter(parent.getContext(), groupPosition+1). Please don't mind but i am trying to execute expandable list with each row containing 3 columns max but failed. So if you can show me how you executing above functionality just by adding GridAdapter code then i can check and modify according to my requirement. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can we work with the GridView as in this, http://majgowrishankar.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-listview-with-radiogroup.html ???

Comment: @rekaszeru is this gridview scrollable?

Comment: @lazylord no, it was meant to expand to its full height.

Comment: @rekaszeru  so how to make it scrollable for supporting pagination

Comment: @rekaszeru just i want to ask i have created my gridview in xml can i use that one

Comment: @rekaszeru if u have any sample code is  working fine can u provide me  and in gridview in need two textview

Comment: @AtulDhanuka You should create your own adapter (extend BaseAdapter for instance), and use your layout with two textviews from that. Sorry, but I don't have any sample layout code at my hand now.

Comment: Hey can you guide me how to do Expandable list with grid items?

Answer (score 3):

all you need to do is change the GrideView with ExpandableHeightGridView

and configure XML with

```
android:isScrollContainer="false"
```

and in code

```
expandableHeightGridView.setExpanded(true);
```

Comment: Your solution works. I think this is the easiest to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

how about using a Gallery instead of GridView?
check [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) out!

Comment: Note that the [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) was deprecated starting API level 16 (Jelly Bean).

Answer (score 1):

Try this github full source code of expendable list view with gridview

https://github.com/coolwd10/ExpandablelistwithGirdview