# How to add a ListView inside a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I already have a `ListView` where each row contains two `TextView`s and a `ImageView`. But what I want to do now is to add number of `ImageView`s into my row. How can i do it? is it by using Nested listviews how to do it? and can i use the same id  `android:id="@android:id/list"`

Comment: Use expandable listview for your purpose...

Comment: simply i need to make something like this https://lh6.ggpht.com/6IdzucfF85DywfqkShiIonyWcEXyg9188pEi6qsYA0Y0sK4CE2LgkYk2TwiZzO8UXDM here the walking man, bus, metro images can be different and number of occurrences also differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should either go for `ExpandableListView`, and add the
  `TextViews` to your `parentView` renderers, or
- You can create your
  own renderer for the list, where each item is a `View` containing the
  two `TextViews` and a `ListView`.

Your inner `ListViews` can have any id attribute, since it does not need to be unique, and from the `Adapter` implementation you will always know exactly where you are (in the tree).

A sample implementation of a nested view [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719637/gridview-inside-expandable-list-in-android/5726131#5726131).