# GridView cells being pushed to the left

Tags: android, android-gridview

How do I dynamically set the height of a cell in GridView, and how do I refresh it? Right now, I have my `Adapter` implement `OnGlobalLayoutListener`, get the dimensions of my GridView when `onGlobalLayout` is called, then save the dimensions. In `getView()`, I call `cell.setLayoutParams(mGridViewWidth / 3, mGridViewWidth / 3);` My problem is that my entire `GridView` is pushed too much to the left so only part of the last column is visible. Calling `notifyDataChanged()` seems to work, but it looks inefficient. I tried `mGridView.requestLayout()` and `mGridView.invalidateViews()` but those didn't work.

I confirmed that my `GridView` takes up the entire screen as it should. It's the elements that are positioned weird. I set my `GridView's` background color to `#0000ff` and the screen was blue. There's something wrong with the elements. Is it wrong for me to recycle `LayoutParams`?

Comment: Will this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5726131/833007) helpful for you? It worked for me pretty well.

Comment: nope, sorry. My GridView is still pushed to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently using `android:stretchMode="none"` destroys the `GridView`. It works now that I removed that bit of code.