# ExpandableLIstView with GridView Child in android

Tags: android, gridview, expandablelistview

I want to add a `GridView` in child of `ExpandableListView`.I came to point that it displays same `child` in all the `groups`.

Can anyone help me out please?
[image: Example image]

Comment: Use RecyclerView for implement this https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view

Comment: Check [GridView inside Expandable list in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719637/gridview-inside-expandable-list-in-android).

Comment: Saw that page @RRR but only expandable adapter class given,not grid adapter class.do you have full coding of it?

Comment: No one will give you full code

Comment: Ya but with only adapter class i couldnt get the results.

Answer (score 2):

I have used GridLayoutManager to achieve the fuctionality.

SectionedExpandableLayoutHelper class gets the data, puts it in required format and passes it to the SectionedExpandableGridAdapter

Helper class created allows the addition/removal of a whole section altogether and also provides with the facility to add/remove individual items from an existing section

https://github.com/SelvaGaneshM/SectionedExpandableGridRecyclerView-master